# My tests are passing, but I always have this warning

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Im using the React-Testing-Library and so far my tests are all passing, but I have a warning which i can't understand or know how to solve.

The warning is....

```
console.error
      Warning: An update to App inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
      
      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
      
      This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act
          at App
```

With the error here in my App.js.

```
 let newData = await random();
      27 |     setData(newData[0]);
    > 28 |     setLoading(false);
         |     ^
      29 |   };
      30 |   useEffect(() => {
      31 |     getter();
```

Here is my App.test file.

```
describe("async call to render Home component", () => {
  test("happy, with data - testing the async call", async () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify([{ test: "data" }]));
    render(<App />)
    const element = await screen.findByTestId('homeComponent')
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
  test("sad, no data - testing the async call",  async () => {
    fetch.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify({}))
    render(<App />)
    const element = await screen.getByText(/loading.../i)
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

I'm not sure if it's just the process in which the tests are going through, with the async function. But still a bit unsure, if the warning may be an issue later on i'd rather sort it out now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the full code for the component under test.

Answer (score -1):

Everytime you render your component with `render(<App />)`, you update the state of the component with the `setLoading(false)` function call.

The React-Testing-Library is warning you to only run state changing functions if the are wrapped inside `act(...)`.

To remove the warning, change your test to use this:

```
act(() => {
    render(<App />)
});
```

PS: Try reading your error messages more carefully. The warning links you to [the react documentation on `act`](https://reactjs.org/link/wrap-tests-with-act), which explains exactly how to solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I did try this and the warning still came up

Comment: Could you post the full source of your test and app files? @fluffy-lionz